# AppStore: send test account for application validation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've just submitted an application to the AppStore, but I need to provide a test account to Apple guys. Is there a process for this ? I did not see any possibility during the app submission process.

Comment: You can send info via "Review Notes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When submitting the application, you can add additional information to the review notes within iTunes Connect, this is where you provide user credentials.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to supply them with any test account information.  Apple has a magical secret way of testing In-App Purchases etc. without a test account.  They don't need your help to do that.  I've actually spoken to Apple Developer Support about this.

I've done this successfully many times before; I assure you it won't be a problem.

Comment: I've heard of several apps being rejected as no test accounts was provided.